# The numeric indicators for tag badge progress have been removed; by design?

Tags: support, profile-page, tag-badges, badge-progress

Within the **Activity** section of the (new) user profile pages is a **Next tag badge:** section.
Within this one used to have both "progress bar" *and* numeric indicators.  Now only plain progress bars without `xxx/200` numbers remain.  Is this change intentional or accidental, and if intentional how was this decision made?

Comment: @Catija Yes, damn it.  I looked first too.

Comment: @Catija Okay, I'll tell myself that so I feel better. ;-)